# Rails: ruby class name must base on file name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-grape

I'm learning `rails` 5.0. When I learn Ruby, I know that ruby file name can be different with class name inside. But when I move to rails, I see that ruby file name and class name must have same format. For example, a class name `CheckInDetail` will be in `check_in_detail.ruby`. I also see that the module name must be matched with directory name. For example, module `authentication` must be inside `authentication` directory. Some example for my conclusion is:

1. `rspec`:  class name must base on file name.
2. `grape`: class name must base on file name. Also module name must be matched with directory.

If I don't follow those convention, when compiling rails will throw exception. I don't see those conventions on those library github pages. Will this true for whole rail project, with all libraries ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With rails there is a convention how you should define classes and file names. A class named ManageOrder should reside inside a file named manage_order.rb. This is a standard convention that rails follows otherwise rails won't be able to load the class.

Comment: thanks for letting know. how about module, we must follow this convention also ?

Comment: Yes you should follow the same convention for modules as well.